# Checking the HTML structure with XPATH, any count of nodes

Tags: xpath

I want to check the structure of some html piece of markup, just checking the structure.
For example I need to check that SOMEWHERE in `<list-item-canvas>` tag is <`image name='category-pic'>` tag.

I write:

```
//div[@class='list-item-canvas'][1]/*/img[@name='category-pic']
```

That's working if `<img>` is a second node after any ('*') node in the hierarchy, **BUT** if I have `<img>` somewhere deep-deep in the structure, AND **I do not want to care about the level hierarchy** how then I should write my xpath-query? I would think that instead `'*'` I might write `'**'` but I can not..

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//div[@class='list-item-canvas'])[1]//img[@name='category-pic']
```

This selects any `img` the string value of whose `name` attribute is `'category-pic'` and that is a descendant of the first (in document order) `div` the string value of whose `class` attribute is `'list-item-canvas'`.

**Do note the bracets surrounding the subexpression**:

```
(//div[@class='list-item-canvas'])[1]
```

this is quite different from:

```
 //div[@class='list-item-canvas'][1]
```

the latter selects *every* `div` element in the document that is the first `div` child of its parent -- and there may be potentially more than one such elements.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
//div[@class='list-item-canvas'][1]//img[@name='category-pic']
```

The `//` before `img` lets you find any descendant of the `div` that is an `img`, instead of just children or grandchildren of the `div`.

Also are you sure you want the `[1]` there? It may not be doing what you think.